# Generic Base Respose models in Kotlin

Tags: api, kotlin, generics

Everyone following is my json response:

```
{
    "requestResponse": {
        "status": 1,
        "result": true,
        "msg": "Success"
    },
    "userId": 5504
}
```

And following is my Base Response class:

```
class BaseResponses<T>{
    lateinit var requestResponse: RequestResponse
}
```

and following are my User data class parameters.

```
data class User(val userId:Int)
```

And below as implementation:

```
   @POST(ApiUrls.CREATE_USER)
    fun createUser(@Body body: CreateUser): Single<BaseResponses<User>>
```

my question is that how can I access T type which is **User** in the Base class would highly appreciate the help.

Thanks

Comment: > "that how can I access T type which is User in the Base class" .... You should clarify your question. The type is not something you "access" - you would access a variable that is of that type.

Comment: what would be the work around to access User class in Base class.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Knowing the type in advance is the exact opposite of the purpose of a generic type. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to create a BaseResponse class, in each API responseStatus is common,  which has key responseStatus in josn, other keys as data class to I can pass as type.

Comment: And want to access these all paratmer from BaseResponse class like User data class

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a genetic type - you need to inherit the properties.

```
data class BaseResponses { // Remove T, it's doing nothing
    lateinit var requestResponse: RequestResponse
}

// Extend base class to inherit common `requestResponse` field
data class User(val userId:Int) : BaseResponses()

// User now will contain requestResponse object
@POST(ApiUrls.CREATE_USER)
fun createUser(@Body body: CreateUser): Single<User>
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be understanding you wrong, you just want to re-use the `RequestResponse` class since it is generic and will be common in all your APIs. So just have it as a parameter in `User` data class.

So it will be like this

```kotlin
data class User(
        val requestResponse: RequestResponse,
        val userId: Int
)
```

Now you can simply access it directly from `User` object. You can even go a step further and assign it default values like this

```kotlin
data class User(
        val requestResponse: RequestResponse = RequestResponse(),
        val userId: Int = 0
)

data class RequestResponse(
        val msg: String = "",
        val result: Boolean = false,
        val status: Int = 0
)
```